# ASP .Net MVC page set ID of @Html.CheckBoxFor using model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to set the id of a @Html.CheckBoxFor using data from the page model.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsOpen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom-control-input switcher", @disabled = "disabled", @id = "cbxOpen_@item.Id" })
```

The last part "cbxOpen_@item.Id" is not working, I would like it to render: id="cbxOpen_1" where 1 is the item id.
But it obviously renders as a string e.g. id="cbxOpen_@item.Id"

Is there a way to make it use the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part `@id = "cbxOpen_@item.Id"` to `@id = "cbxOpen_" & item.Id`

Comment: Sorry I used VB syntax instead of C#

Answer (score 0):

Just handle it as you would in C# normally:

```
@id = $"cbxOpen_{item.Id}"
```